# General statement about how many lines in Euclidean space will determine a line

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, grassmannian

It is easy to see that in $3$-dimensional Euclidean space, given $4$ lines in general position, there exists precisely one line who intersects with each of the $4$ lines. We call the $4$ lines determined this line.

I want to know the analogue of this statement in higher dimension, i.e. for given positive integers $N=n+m+1$, how many $n$-planes in general position will determine one $m$-plane in $N$-dimensional total space? If we denote the number by $d(n,m)$, for example the first paragraph just says $d(1,1)=4$. Then is there a formula for $d(n,m)$?

---

**Edit**

I just realized that we may not get *one* $m$-plane in general. It should be *finite* instead.

---

**Edit'**

Now I found the finite intersection may also not happen. The question now we should ask is, for which $n,m$ we will have the finite interstion case?

My approach is to compute the dimension of $X(V^n)\subset \mathbb G(m,N)$ where $X(V^n)$ consists of all $m$-plane in $\mathbb P^N$ which intersects with the $n$-plane $V^n$. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Interesting question! What are your thoughts on the problem? What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Servaes  I think one way is to consider the subset $X(V^n)\subset \mathbb G(m,N)$ which intersects with the $n$-plane $V^n$ and compute its dimension. And I don't know how to compute it.

Comment: "It is easy to see that in 3-dimensional Euclidean space, given 4 lines in general position, there exists precisely one line who intersects with each of the 4 lines. We call the 4 lines determined this line." That is not true --- in fact, 4 lines determine exactly 2 lines. Update: OK, I see you mentioned this in the edit.

Comment: @Art Yes you are right, I have also realized this. See the first "Edit" below.

Comment: Anyway, under the assumption that $N=n+m+1$, the dimension of the set you call $X(V^n)$ is always just one less than the dimension of $\mathbf G(m,N)$. So the number of $n$-planes you need is exactly the dimension of $\mathbf G(m,N)$, namely $(m+1)(N-m)=(m+1)(n+1)$.

Comment: @Art Could you explain a little why the codimension is one? I am not familiar with this.

Comment: I don't understand your statement. If you ask for how many lines in $\Bbb P^3$ (over the complex numbers) intersect 4 given lines the answer is 2. We can e.g assume that $L_1, L_2$ intersects by perturbing and same with $L_3,L_4$. Now obviously the line $M$ passing by $L_1 \cap L_2$ and $L_3 \cap L_4$ intersects all the 4 lines. Also if $P,Q$ are the planes spanned by $L_1, L_2$ (resp. $L_3,L_4$) they intersect in a line $N$ which also works (this solution was by Schubert). Over noncompact things intersection numbers are not well defined.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Yes, I consider the intersection in $\mathbb P^N$. I stated the question in Euclidean space because in the generic case the answer is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unresolved question in the comments is why intersection with a linear space of dimension one less than complementary defines a codimension-1 subset of the Grassmannian.

So suppose we have linear spaces of dimensions $m$ and $n$ in a space of dimension $m+n+1$. Passing to the associated vector spaces, these correspond to vector subspaces $U_{m+1}$ and $V_{n+1}$ in a space $W$ of dimension $m+n+2$.

Now the condition that the linear spaces intersect in $\mathbf P^{m+n+1}$ translates to the condition that $U$ and $V$ have nonzero intersection in $W$ --- in other words, that they fail to span $W$.

We can change basis on $W$ so that $U$ is simply the subspace spanned by the first $m+1$ basis vectors. Choosing a basis for $V$ and forming the matrix whose first $m+1$ columns are the basis vectors of $U$ and whose last $n+1$ columns are the basis vectors of $W$ we get something of the form

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
I & A \\
0 & B
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the diagonal blocks have sizes $(m+1) \times (m+1)$ and $(n+1) \times (n+1)$.

The fact that $U$ and $V$ together fail to span $W$ is equivalent to the condition that this matrix has determinant 0. On the other hand, due to the block form the determinant is evidently equal to $\operatorname{det}(B)$, so again our condition is equivalent to 
$$\operatorname{det}(B)=0.$$

But the Plücker coordinates of $\mathbf P(W)$ are precisely the $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ minors of the matrix
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
 A \\
 B
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $\operatorname{det}(B)$ is one of those minors. So the condition of intersecting $\mathbf P(V)$ nontrivially is precisely the vanishing of one Plücker coordinate, and in particular the corresponding subset of $\mathbf G$ has codimension 1.

---

Let me finish by saying that this is the tip of the iceberg of the beatiful and important topic of *Schubert calculus*. You can read about this in *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths and Harris, or for a friendlier exposition the new book *3264 And All That* by Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.